# Write Res (Residue) function with evaluation point below Res

Tags: latex

I'm using the \usepackage{physics} package, which has a command \Res to create residues.  However, when using this command as \Res_{z = z_0}, the point of evaluation appears as a subscript rather than as a limit.  Is there any way to redefine the operator such that it looks like \lim_{z = z_0}, where the evaluation point is below the operator?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{physics}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    \Res_{z = z_0}
    &&
    \lim_{z = z_0}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{physics}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    \mathop{\mathrm{Res}}_{z = z_0}
    &&
    \lim_{z = z_0}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you so much!

Comment: @JustinMurante You're welcome!